# Expected time for multiple independent coupon collectors to finish

Tags: order-statistics, coupon-collector

I have a problem where there are $C$ independent coupon collectors and there are 5 coupons in total. All $C$ collectors have already collected the first three coupons and have to finish collecting the remaining two. At each timestep $t$, each coupon collector will try to get a coupon with probability $0 \lt p_i \leq 1$, where $i \in \{1,...,C\}$. This means that at any given timestep, 0 or more collectors can attempt to get a coupon. Coupons are drawn with equal probability and with replacement.

I would like to know the expected time taken for all $C$ collectors to finish collecting the remaining two coupons. I saw some questions on stackexchange but none were related to my problem setting.

How should I approach this?

Comment: I think where it says $i\in0,1,\ldots,C$ you mean $i\in\{1,\ldots,C\}$?

Comment: @joriki Oh yes that’s a typo. Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: You need to escape braces with slashes; otherwise they're interpreted as grouping control characters and aren't rendered.

Comment: @joriki Again, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By inclusion–exclusion, after $n$ time steps collector $i$ has not finished with probability

$$
2\left(1-\frac15{p_i}\right)^n-\left(1-\frac25{p_i}\right)^n\;.
$$

Thus, all collectors have finished with probability

$$
\mathsf P(N\le n)=\prod_{i=1}^C\left(1-2\left(1-\frac15{p_i}\right)^n+\left(1-\frac25{p_i}\right)^n\right)\;,
$$

so the desired expectation of the number $N$ of time steps required is

\begin{eqnarray}
\mathsf E[N]
&=&
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\mathsf P(N\gt n)
\\
&=&
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(1-\prod_{i=1}^C\left(1-2\left(1-\frac15{p_i}\right)^n+\left(1-\frac25{p_i}\right)^n\right)\right)\;.
\end{eqnarray}

It’s not very enlightening to multiply this out for general $C$, but for concrete values of $C$ and $p_i$ you can multiply it out and sum all the resulting geometric series.

Comment: Great answer! But would there be a way to remove the outer sum somehow, so that I can calculate it directly?

Comment: @SeminPark: That's what I was referring to with the last sentence. If you multiply out the finite product, each term is a geometric series that you can sum. It just doesn't look nice if you write it out for general $C$. There are $3^C-1$ terms.